# In "Avengers Grimm", is there any explanation for Ernst coming back?

Tags: avengers-grimm

I'm watching *[Avengers Grimm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4296026/)*. I know... I brought it upon myself, but my wife has an odd fondness for films from The Asylum. Anyhow, early in the film, Rumpelstiltskin shoots Officer Ernst in the head. Later in the film, he shows up, hunting for Snow White in the storm sewers. How did he come back to life? Or was this just shoddy editing?

Comment: _my wife has an odd fondness for films from The Asylum_... no man should ever have to say those words!